# Simple factory retrieving object by name

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns, factory-method

Despite the fact that this code works, I would like to know if there's any situation I did not anticipated, and/or if what I am trying to do is some what wrong.

**-std=C++11 flag needed**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <functional>

class object
{
    public:

    virtual ~object(){}

    virtual std::string to_string() = 0;
};

class SomeObject : public object
{
    public:

    SomeObject(){}
    virtual ~SomeObject(){}

    virtual std::string to_string()
    {
        return "I am a type of SomeObject";
    } 
};

class SomeOtherObject : public object
{
    public:

    SomeOtherObject(){}
    virtual ~SomeOtherObject(){}

    virtual std::string to_string()
    {
        return "I am a type of SomeOtherObject";
    } 
};

std::map<std::string, std::function<object*()> > types;

template<typename O>
inline
static void register_type(const std::string & name)
{
    types[name] = [](){ return new O; };
}

static object * get_object(const std::string & object_name )
{
    return types[object_name]();
}

int main()
{
    register_type<SomeObject>("SomeObject");
    register_type<SomeOtherObject>("SomeOtherObject");

    object * some = get_object("SomeObject");
    object * some_other = get_object("SomeOtherObject");

    std::cout << "::" << some->to_string() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "::" << some_other->to_string() << std::endl;

    delete some;
    delete some_other;

    std::cout << "exit" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are these the original variable names?  They make this code look hypothetical.

Comment: @Jamal They're probably not. But the technique described works, and can be reviewed from an _abstract_ POV, or not?

Comment: @Jamal I just made this code and compiled with a comipler in a website. I think I can't answer your question properly.

Comment: I've always had reservations about Simple Factory from a security standpoint. Someone (in client code) can create her own concrete class, register it, then have it executed somewhere by just injecting its name... Maybe a lot of ifs, but this seems riskier than static class names.

Comment: but thats my point of using it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general your code looks fine, though there are some points to improve:

**Memory management**

Instead of using raw pointers and `new` `delete`, you should use a smart pointer to express transfer of ownership explicitly:

```
template<typename O>
void register_type(const std::string & name) {
    types[name] = [](){ return std::unique_ptr<O>(new O); };
}

std::unique_ptr<object> get_object(const std::string & object_name ) {
    return types[object_name]();
}
```

Thus it's clear, the caller will own the `object` instance, and doesn't need to struggle calling `delete` correctly if the obtained instance goes out of scope.

**Template parameter naming**

The more usual name for the template parameter is rather `T` than `O`

**Use a factory class instead of global functions and global map**

Consolidate the code of the `register_type()`, `get_object()` functions and the `types` map variable into a `class Registry`, and provide a single instance of that one.

This would allow to encapsulate the `types` map as a private class member.

You could consider making that class a Singleton.

**Check if the type name is registered**

You should check if the string passed to the `get_object()` function was already registered in the map, rather than blindly calling the default (NOP) function from the map.

**Usage of `static` for a global function**

You should be aware that `static` actually make the `register_type()` function only visible for the translation unit, it appears in. Actually you should not need it.

---

BTW, the technique you're using is often seen for unit testing frameworks (like e.g. google-test) as test case factories, also often coming along with stringizing macros for the registered classes.

Comment: I was "hoping" that the idea in general was wrong because I use a template parameter inside a lambda to return a pointer outside compile time. But if it's not the case, I am glad. And I really appreciate your effort and you made me a better programmer. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

- You don't need that space in

  ```
  std::map<std::string, std::function<object*()> > types;
                                                ^
  ```

  anymore. C++11 has learned that `>>` in this case is not the shift operator.
- Why is `register_type` `static` and `inline`? I don't think either one makes sense here.
- Using `T` as the template parameter type is very common, `O` not so much, making the code harder to read.
- Returning a raw owning pointer is bad style in C++11. Return a `std::unique_ptr` instead, since it will prevent a leak by default. If people don't like it they can call `.release()`, so you are not losing flexibility.
- Some people consider `std::endl` bad style since it flushes the output, needlessly slowing down the program.
- Maybe you could extend `register_type` to accept types that are not default constructible.

Answer (score 1):

**Remove unnecessary virtual functions**

In your `SomeObject` and `SomeOtherObject` classes, are you expecting them to be inherited from as well? If not, then remove the `virtual` and use the `override` contextual keyword from C++11 instead. This will allow you to make your intent of overriding the `toString()` function explicit as well as provide a compile-time check for whether or not you're actually overriding the correct function. This might be overkill in this specific example (due to its simplicity) but it's a good habit to get into. You can also remove your unnecessary definition of the default ctors and dtors for these classes (as the compiler provides them automatically for you).

```
class object
{
    public:

    virtual ~object(){}

    virtual std::string to_string() = 0;
};

class SomeObject : public object
{
    public:

    std::string to_string() override
    {
        return "I am a type of SomeObject";
    } 
};

class SomeOtherObject : public object
{
    public:

    std::string to_string() override
    {
        return "I am a type of SomeOtherObject";
    } 
};
```

**Use a Factory Registry Class / Memory Management**

As others have mentioned, turn your global map and registry/unregister functions into a class that can manage its own state. Moreover, use `std::unique_ptr` instead of operator `new` here.

**Replace std::map with std::unordered_map**

It looks like you don't need the ordering (and consequently the `log(n)` insertion time) that std::map gives you. If you're looking for a hash table (amortized `O(1)` insertion/retrieval), then use std::unordered_map.

**Extending register_type() for non default constructable objects**

Use variadic templates for this:

```
struct Registry
{

    template <class T, class... Args>
    static void register_type(const std::string &name, Args&&... args)
    {
        types[name] = [&args...]() { return std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...); };
    }

    static std::unique_ptr<object> get_object(const std::string &name)
    {
        return types[name]();
    }

private:
    static std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<std::unique_ptr<object>()>> types;
};
```

Comment: Not using `virtual` does not have any effect on the classes, as the affected members are overriding inherited virtual functions. It duplicates part of the info provided by `override` without adding anything new though, which is not good.

Comment: Ah, I was under the impression that adding `virtual` in a derived class when it wasn't needed would generate an unnecessary vtable. I wonder where I got that from? Anyways, `override` does that better now and provides a compile time check :)
I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Nearly everything is already handled in the other answers, but anyway:

1. Indenting the access-specifier `public:` to the same level as the members is uncommon, you want it to stand out:

   Indent it to the same level as the containing class.
2. If you want the default implementation for a special member function (default/copy/move constructor, copy/move assignment, destructor), prefer implicit declaration over explicit defaulting `= default;` in-class, over explicit defaulting outside the class over providing it yourself.

   Only if it is not user-provided can it be *trivial*, which can be detected and is optimized for.

   (Applying this means that none of your example-classes retain any explicitly declared member but `to_string`).
3. Consider adding a namespace-scope `to_string`, to follow the pattern of `std::to_string`.
4. Declaring a free function both `static` and `inline`, while not an error, is certainly futile:

   - `static` means it is translation-unit (TU) local.
   - `inline` means it is not an error if the function is provided by multiple TUs, as long as it's identical in every instance.
5. `return 0;` is implicit for `main`.